# Loop through excel spreadsheet using macro

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, macros

I'm trying to loop through excel cells to get value from sql server table. I've written a macro that will take the jobnumber from the excel and query sql server tale to get customer details and dump it on the spreadsheet. So far I'm only able to get data for single cell. How can I loop through the excel cells for more than one jobnumber. I'm new to VBA. Thanks for your help. Here is my macro:

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim newrow As String



newrow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, "A").Value

' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=0.0.0.0;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=asset;" & _
              "User ID=Temp;Password=test123;"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT customer FROM job_tab where jobnum2='" & Trim(newrow) & "';")

' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.
    Sheets(1).Range("B1").CopyFromRecordset rs
' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

' Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so, by using the IN SQL statement:

```
SELECT customer FROM job_tab WHERE jobnum2 IN ( 'Value1', 'Value2', ... );
```

Therefore you have to loop through all the customers in column A of your table and alter the SQL request to use the above mentioned statement:

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim newrow As String


'MODIFIED: create the search string for the IN-Statement
newrow = "("
For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    newrow = newrow & "'" & Trim(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, "A").value) & "',"
Next i
newrow = Left(newrow, Len(newrow) - 1)
newrow = newrow & ")"

' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=0.0.0.0;" & _
              "Initial Catalog=asset;" & _
              "User ID=Temp;Password=test123;"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString
'MODIFIED: altered the SQL statement to use the search string with IN
Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT customer FROM job_tab where jobnum2 IN " & newrow & "';")

' Check we have data.
If Not rs.EOF Then
    ' Transfer result.
    Sheets(1).Range("B1").CopyFromRecordset rs
' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
Else
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

' Clean up
If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: @lchixgo - Thank you for your response. I tried using the code you suggested. I'm getting below error message. Runtime Error -2147217900 (80040e14)

Automation Error

Comment: @lchixgo-I'm getting an error message on this line. Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT customer FROM job_tab where jobnum2 IN " & newrow & "';")

Comment: @Ichixgo- Any help is appreciated. Stuck with this issue for too long. Thanks

Comment: @LearningMacro what kind of SQL server/DB are u using? The error seems to be caused by the SQL statement.

Could you add the following line right before the error throwing line and post the output from the VBA console here:

    Debug.Print "SELECT customer FROM job_tab where jobnum2 IN " & newrow & "';"

Comment: @Ichixgo- I'm using SQL server 2000. I commented out the line where I was getting an error. I also added the line "Debug.Print "SELECT customer FROM job_tab where jobnum2 IN " & newrow & "';" –".  Here is the error on the VBA console: Run-time error '3704': Application defined or object defined error.

Comment: @LearningMacro could you provide a screen of the debug.print part of your code, the vba consoles output and the error message?

Comment: @Ichixgo-I'm getting this error message after using debug.print: System Error &H80040E14 (-2147217900). Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108424/discussion-between-ichixgo-and-learningmacro).

Comment: @Ichixgo- Finally got it working. Thanks a lot. The only thing I need to check now is if there is no match for job number in the db, I need to add a column saying "Job # not found". Thanks again

Comment: @LearningMacro could you provide us with the solution you came up with or what's wrong with my solution, that it didn't work for you at first?